# fetch collection using rest api in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

In that rest api url, i am getting an json array and have fetch it with EmployeeList collection. using the fetch() only call the rest api. If I didnt use the fetch, the rest api call doesnt work, it tested using the log in api-code. while fetching I get all the details, but I am getting the error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.model is not a constructor   backbone-min.js:24
```

I am new to the backbonejs. Whats the error, why this error will happens. My code is below,

```
var app = {};
app.Employee = Backbone.Model.extend();
app.employee = new app.Employee();
app.EmployeeList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.employee,
    url:'/api/employ',
    parse: function(response) {
        return response;
    }
})
app.employeeList = new app.EmployeeList();
app.employeeList.fetch();
app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#emp',
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        console.log(app.employeeList);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html('sathish');
    }
});
app.appView = new app.AppView();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
app.EmployeeList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.employee,
    .....
})
```

To

```
app.EmployeeList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Employee,
    ...
})
```

the model param should be a model class(a constructor function in js) like app.Employee.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide `app.Employee()` instead of `new app.Employee()` as a model parameter of the collection.

Comment: When Use like that the error is left hand side assignment error,